# How to deploy .war file to glassfish server?

Tags: java, deployment, glassfish, war

I've created a a .war file and now I want to deploy it to glassfish, but when I deploy it, I received an error

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
```

Exception Description: Configuration error.  Class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] not found.

How to fix the error? Can someone give me an detailed instruction for deploy .war file to glassfish server?

Comment: it seems to be a problem with your persistence.xml check your logs and post a little more detail thanks

Comment: It cant find your jdbc driver. Check your glassfish configuration